# Clojure Quote With Numbers

Tags: macros, clojure

I cannot figure out why '50% and '50x throw exceptions in clojure. I want to make a macro that accepts 50% into a parameter, but I keep getting exceptions. Is it possible and how?

[Edit]
OK, so, you will laugh, but I was doing it more for a joke DSL, but now I am actually curious.

```
(defmacro chance [x]
   (let [y (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/replace (str x) "%" ""))]
     `(> ~y (rand-int 100))))
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us your Macro?

Comment: 50% or 50X aren't numbers any way.

Comment: I don't want a number, I want a quoted form, like 'a or 'b

Comment: ``(chance "50%")`` works for me (it's supposed to return ``true``/``false``, right?). I guess, ``"50x"`` would work too if you add the corresponding condition.

Comment: Run (str '50%) in your REPL and see what is happening

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I thought @Steve just forgot to put quotes around them.

Comment: A non-numeric prefix suffices for making a readable symbol: `'_50%`, also `:50%` is a valid keyword.

Comment: Regarding DSLs and macros: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yvrs9S0RIw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just quote any sequence of characters, you can only quote valid Clojure *forms*; the quoted expression must be `(read)`able and it must be a single expression.

`50x` and `50%` are not valid symbols or numbers, quoted or not, since numbers may not end with an x or a % and symbols may not start with a digit. They're also not valid string literals, since strings must be quoted with double quotes. See also http://clojure.org/reader

Comment: Yep the section on that page about valid symbols was the explanation I missed. Thanks!

Comment: it is possible to have 50% as a symbol: `(symbol "50%")` does this. The problem is there is no reader syntax that will create that symbol. It may or may not be possible to have a reader macro that turns `#sym 50%` into a proper symbol. And it may or may not be worth it to do such a thing.

Comment: "It may or may not be possible to have a reader macro that turns #sym 50% into a proper symbol." - it's not, because 50% is not a valid reader construct - #foo EXPR constructs only work where EXPR is a valid clojure expression.